# python read file and output into format string

Tags: python

I have a sample json file example below

```
    {
      "email": "string",
      "cont_pic": "string",
      "title": "string",
      "user_cd": "string",
      "type4": "string"
    }
```

and want to convert into a formatted string like example below  , it will convert into public static XX= 'yy';
Where XX is the Upper case of yy

```
  public static EMAIL= 'email';
  public static CONTACT_PIC = 'cont_pic';
  public static TITLE = 'title';
  public static USER_CODE = 'user_cd';
  public static TYPE4 = 'type4';
```

I have stuck at below code

```
filename = "file.json"
with open(filename) as f:
    contents = f.read()
    contents = contents.split(':')
    print(contents)
```

Comment: what would yy be though

Comment: this is not a textfile so you can't parse it with just ***f.read()*** !
you should parse json i recommend you to study about json in python first. check below link :
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `json` module to parse the JSON file in Python like I did below:

```py
import json

with open("file.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

    for key in data:
        print(f"public static {key.upper()} = '{key}';")
```

Output:

```
public static EMAIL = 'email';
public static CONT_PIC = 'cont_pic';
public static TITLE = 'title';
public static USER_CD = 'user_cd';
public static TYPE4 = 'type4';
```

Comment: this work great!  
if I have a json field like "serviceChanged": true, how can I based on the camel case to convert it become  public static SERVICE_CHANGED= 'serviceChanged';

Comment: @B.Cos If my answer solved your problem please click on the checkmark next to my answer. Please post your question about the camel case as a separate question so that it will be easier for people with the same problem in the future, to find the answer quickly.